# Converting Shp file to .osm.pbf file

Tags: python, openstreetmap, shapefile, osm.pbf

I am trying to convert a GIS LINE shapefile into a .osm.pbf file.

I've done some research on the topic and some tools that kept coming out are:

- Merkaator
- shp2osm - which deals mostly with point shapefile
- shape2osm.py - which keeps bringing up an error with importing elementtree.SimpleXMLWriter

But nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Offtopic for StackOverflow since this is not a programming question. Try http://gis.stackexchange.com/ or http://help.openstreetmap.org/

Comment: Thanks @scai  ! I completely forgot about those pages.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the problem and solved using JOSM and two different plugins:

JOSM -> https://josm.openstreetmap.de/

OpenData -> https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/OpenData

PBF -> https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/PBF

With this three pices you will be able to convert a .shp file into a .osm.pbf (and probably others formats).